# How to get Maximum App requests per day

Tags: facebook

Most of Zynga games use the Maximum App requests per day to show to the user how many requests he can send that day. I couldn't figure out how to get that daily number (dynamically) . Any hints on that? Since, I'm doing this in a flash app. I can't let the user send requests more than he is allowed. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out your Requests limit via the Developer Settings page:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Note that limits only apply to the older method of sending requests. If you use the newer Requests functionality, there is no limit to the amount of requests you can send:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Naturally, if you're being spammy, you'll still get reported a lot and automated systems could block you, so remember to keep to a reasonable volume of requests.